# HttpServletRequestをActionRedirectに入れたい

Tags: java, struts

HttpServletRequestをActionRedirectに入れ、リクエストを受取った先では、上記HttpServletRequestを使用したいと考えています。
ActionRedirectのaddParameterでHttpServletRequestを入れようと思ったのですが、String型になってしまうため上手くいきませんでした。

解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらくStruts1.2または1.3での話と推察されますので、それを前提で回答します。

ActionRedirectは、リダイレクト用のクラスです。
addParameterは「リクエストパラメータを追加する」メソッドですので、HttpServletRequestインスタンスを詰めることができません。

おそらく実現したいことは、遷移先のURLでもHttpServletRequestに格納した属性などを共有したいのではないかと思いますが、その場合はForwardingActionForwardを使います。

以下のドキュメントも参考にしてください。

- ActionRedirect ( ActionRedirect - Techscore様 )
  http://www.techscore.com/tech/Java/ApacheJakarta/Struts/24-2/
- ForwardingActionForward ( Struts1.2 - 日本語Javadoc )
  http://www.jajakarta.org/struts/struts1.2/documentation/ja/target/api/org/apache/struts/action/ForwardingActionForward.html
- リダイレクトとフォワードの違いを知る
  http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fjava/javatips/062jspservlet029.html

参考になれば幸いです。